# AC box fan controlled from PC 3pin 12vdc chassis fan port

Tags: relay

I have a Relay [793-P-1C], and I was thinking about using it to control an AC fan.  Would this work? I've made a crude schematic for what I'm thinking.

Is this an okay way to do this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffi3qg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Assuming you have a ? V switch and reverse diode to drive the coil, ok

Comment: I see you want to drive using the PC  fan port as the assumption in your question. Assuming on/off , i guess it is ok, but what is the AC box fan for? Cooling the PC?  Maybe there are better solutions. Need a lot more details on why it is hot and why you think a dust collecting big fan is good?

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit to understand your drawing. When I realized we were looking at mechanical drawing it fell into place. You have it correct, the relay will support a few amps so as long as the fan is rated lower than the relay contact current (16A 240VAC) it should be just fine. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

When controlling a motor with a relay, you need to check the inductive load rating of the contacts. For USA and Canada standards, horsepower is usually listed. Elsewhere the power factor (p.f.) or phase displacement is listed. There are also usage class code numbers that may be published. Note that, for this relay, the safe current level for a motor is half the safe level for a resistive load. The contact life can be expected to be considerably less for motor operation. It may or may not be published. UL standards may state a minimum expected life.

[image]